# Meteor. Should I subscribe to entire DB on startup?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I develop a meteor app for internal use in a company. It tracks people and allows a manager to assign tasks to different employees. I therefore expect that the DB will remain relatively small.

I am aware that it is good practice to dynamically subscribe to the DB subset that is currently used in the different views.

However, I thought that it might be acceptable in my case with little content to simply subscribe to everything at startup. Does anybody have experience with this practice and how it performs with increasing DB size?

Comment: `meteor add autopublish`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't. It may add too much weight to your page, making it sluggish and unresponsive for users.
Instead consider limiting the data your subscribing to, on a page-by-page basis.
For example, a page for a unique employee, should only have the data relevant to that employee -> `myCollectionName.findOne({id: routePageId});`

Answer (score 0):

You just need a anonymous publish function like this on the server:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return [
    CollectionOne.find(),
    CollectionTwo.find()
  ]
});
```

This will automatically publish the collections you want to show, because even if there is not much data, there will be some sensible data..

Comment: I already do that to filter sensitive information (e.g. user data).
I was wondering how large those collections can be without influencing performance.

Comment: I am not talking about autopublish. I define my individual publishers. I am referring to calling all subscriptions when the user opens the app in the browser instead of individually subscribing to the data needed by the different views